# Why does phpMyAdmin take a long time to display a query, yet shows that the query executed fast?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm tying to execute a query in phpMyAdmin.  The query takes approximately two minutes to load, but at the top of the query results it says that the "Query took 0.2768 sec".  How is this possible?

Comment: do you have an extremely large result set?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I set LIMIT 0,30.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293336/467164

Comment: The only thing I can tell is that, if your query statement is very long - it's possible that PHPMyAdmin doesn't check to see if there's a LIMIT clause in it.

Is your query statement pretty big?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The larger your resultset, the slower phpMyAdmin is. The phpMyAdmin script receives the query result from MySQL in 0.2768 seconds. It then must parse the thousands of rows/columns of data in this and apply all the markup necessary to display it in your browser. This eats up time, and memory. I suggest using a command-line client if speed is a concern.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks hobodave.  Is that the case even if I set LIMIT 0,30?

Comment: That should speed up the php side of things, yes.

Comment: In MySQL command line one of my queries takes 50s to execute, on PhpMyAdmin same time but it says that it took 0.2s. Looks like PhpMyAdmin is not talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The query executed fast, but phpMyAdmin took a long time to load it.

Comment: Right, but why would that happen?  For other queries there doesn't seem to be a disconnect between phpMyAdmin load time and the query execution time, so my phpMyAdmin isn't systematically slow.  It's something about this query.